# How to view version of a ppt file?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

In my computer MS office 2013 is installed. I have a set of ppt files, I would like to see the version(2002, 2003 . . 2007,2010) of the PPT file. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: PowerPoint files don't have a direct version (other than PPT vs PPTX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the version of PowerPoint that created the file (or perhaps that last saved it?) tack .ZIP onto the end of the filename (ie, myfile.pptx.zip) and open it in Windows Explorer or any ZIP utility you like.

In the \docProps folder, you'll find app.xml and near the end of this file you'll find xx.0000

XX will be 14 for PPT 2010, 15 for PPT 2013, 16 for PPT 2016

Comment: Thank you somuch. This works. Could you also tell how to find 2007,2003 please.

Comment: I think the versioning is something that was added due to user requests in 2010. I haven't checked, but from your question, I'd guess that you're not seeing it in files from 2007, and there's nothing in 2003 and prior files that identifies version, at least not that I'm aware of.  So I guess the short answer is "No, sorry."

Comment: Thank you Steve. The method you mentioned works on the office versions which were built on standard XML format. Before 2007, office files were in flat file format. Anyways, thank you somuch.

Answer (score -1):

Office 2013
- See link below
http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/interface/2013/determine-service-pack-1-office-2013.html

PowerPoint 2010
- Open the ppt file
- Click one File
- Select Help
- You will see the version on your right hand side.

Comment: I don't find any help option in Powerpoint 2013 version on clicking File.

Comment: The method you suggest here gives you the version and build number of the currently running instance of PowerPoint.  @KrishnaTeja wants to know what version of PowerPoint created a particular PowerPoint *file*.